# Pandas messing up dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm creating a data frame in Pandas—

```
df_data = dict()

for x in data:
    series = pandas.Series(x['value']['values'], index=x['value']['timestamps'])

    df_data[x['_id']] = series

df = pandas.DataFrame(df_data)
```

`data` is a list of dicts in the format—

```
{u'_id': u'770000000049',
 u'value': {u'timestamps': [datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 25, 10, 16, 1, 270000),
                            datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 25, 10, 18, 29, 745000),
                            datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 25, 10, 21, 54, 931000),
                            datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 25, 10, 23, 18, 896000)],
            u'values': [204.0, 16.788, 139.2, 116.004]}}
```

Printing an example series gives me—

```
>>> print df_data['770000000049']

>>> 2012-07-25 10:16:01.270000    204.000
2012-07-25 10:18:29.745000     16.788
2012-07-25 10:21:54.931000    139.200
2012-07-25 10:23:18.896000    116.004
```

As expected. However, printing the resulting data frame gives me—

```
>>> print df['770000000049']

>>> 1992-06-05 15:50:11.527680   NaN
2181-10-17 22:55:34.850625   NaN
2215-08-27 21:41:15.306049   NaN
1936-05-22 00:55:45.848401   NaN
1783-06-08 06:38:26.257076   NaN
2017-03-12 18:30:17.469108   NaN
2209-08-06 03:45:09.779652   NaN
1768-02-06 12:00:22.653272   NaN
1916-07-20 06:51:31.628376   NaN
2086-01-25 18:30:58.261336   NaN
1940-08-26 15:13:33.790568   NaN
1712-12-17 22:48:01.743241   NaN
1803-06-16 16:32:58.309017   NaN
1981-11-05 04:38:27.140059   NaN
2246-05-25 09:09:27.875035   NaN
...
```

WTF! The data is all wrong. Both keys and values are completely wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: Printing `df` gives me—

```
DatetimeIndex: 386 entries, 1992-06-05 15:50:11.527680 to 1774-08-13 02:00:15.237103
Data columns:
770000000006    0  non-null values
770000000009    0  non-null values
770000000010    0  non-null values
770000000011    0  non-null values
770000000012    0  non-null values
770000000013    0  non-null values
770000000018    0  non-null values
770000000020    0  non-null values
770000000021    0  non-null values
770000000022    0  non-null values
770000000024    0  non-null values
770000000029    0  non-null values
770000000030    0  non-null values
770000000032    0  non-null values
770000000034    0  non-null values
770000000049    0  non-null values
dtypes: float64(16)
```

Completely wrong

**Edit 2**:

I've [written a module](http://pastebin.com/WTsCkKrL) that reproduces the bug for me.

Comment: Please post bug reports in GitHub, not StackOverflow

Comment: @WesMcKinney Well, I'm not sure it's a legitimate bug. But it certainly looks suspect. I'm more wondering if I've done something wrong

Comment: I can reproduce it (see edit2) and opened an issue for this on GitHub: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1753

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: It *is* a bug. I (Wes) fixed it here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/aea7c4522bd7beffd0df80efee818873110609fa

---

It turns out [it's not a bug](http://pandas.sourceforge.net/timeseries.html#time-series-related-instance-methods)—

> While pandas does not force you to have a sorted date index, some of these methods may have unexpected or incorrect behavior if the dates are unsorted. So please be careful.

Sorting the dates at the DB level fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the snippet you pasted and it seems fine to me. What version of pandas/numpy are you using? Can you post all/more of the data?

```
In [26]: paste
{u'_id': u'770000000049',
 u'value': {u'timestamps': [datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 25, 10, 16, 1, 270000),
                            datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 25, 10, 18, 29, 745000),
                            datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 25, 10, 21, 54, 931000),
                            datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 25, 10, 23, 18, 896000)],
            u'values': [204.0, 16.788, 139.2, 116.004]}}
## -- End pasted text --
Out[26]: 
{u'_id': u'770000000049',
 u'value': {u'timestamps': [datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 25, 10, 16, 1, 270000),
   datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 25, 10, 18, 29, 745000),
   datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 25, 10, 21, 54, 931000),
   datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 25, 10, 23, 18, 896000)],
  u'values': [204.0, 16.788, 139.2, 116.004]}}

In [27]: data = [_]

In [28]: paste
df_data = dict()

for x in data:
    series = pandas.Series(x['value']['values'], index=x['value']['timestamps'])

    df_data[x['_id']] = series

df = pandas.DataFrame(df_data)
## -- End pasted text --

In [29]: print df['770000000049']
2012-07-25 10:16:01.270000    204.000
2012-07-25 10:18:29.745000     16.788
2012-07-25 10:21:54.931000    139.200
2012-07-25 10:23:18.896000    116.004
Name: 770000000049
```

Comment: Thanks Chang. I'll update the question with more "reproducible" code